# Dynamic SQL with servlets

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a servlet called `DBChart` mapped to url `/db`.the servlet outputs some data based on the sql query used here.

**What I have:**

At client end, I am making an ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                async: false,
                url : 'http://localhost:8080/DBCHART/db',
                success : function(data) {/*some code*/})
```

and At server end, a static query that says:

```
String sql ="select * from Employee"
```

**What I want:**
 I want to be able to pass some parameters here like :

```
url: http://localhost:8080/DBCHART/db?Name = 'xyz'?Age = 21
```

and at server end, the query in this case should become:

```
select * from Employee where Name ='xyz' and Age = 21
```

i.e only if those parameters were supllied otherwise it should stay

```
select * from Employee
```

Can I please get some direction to create dynamic sql for this efficiently?

Answer (score -1):

let's say in this case you're using varName as 'xyz' and varAge as 21
-- -- Name = 'xyz'?Age = 21

you can use some logic like this (point to ponder: WHERE 1 = 1 )

```
string sqlQuery = " select * from Employee where 1 = 1 ";

if(null != varName && !varName.isEmpty())){
   // add criteria for Name
   sqlQuery += " AND Name = '"+ varName + "'"; // TODO: use parametrized query
}

if(null != varAge && varAge > 0){
    // add criteria for Age
   sqlQuery += " AND Age = "+ varAge ;  // TODO: use parametrized query
}
```

Comment: This answer is going in the right direction, but it's flawed because of secuirty issues. It mentions parameterized queries, but the code samples don't use them. The example is _crazy-vulnerable_ to injection attacks. -1

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: How do I overcome such vulnerabilities ?Can I have seomething in that direction,please?

Comment: @Raushan: How do I take out varName and varAge out of that url String ?

Comment: the code that i've given is just to give you the logic, how to proceed. you've to implement it with parameterized query, otherwise it's vulnerable to sql-injection. see this java doc for parameterized query (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)    ... for query string you can get detail from here [https://java.net/projects/urlencodedquerystring/pages/Home]